# JSON data print in react-js

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json

I try to print student details in react app. its work but printing format is not correct. I store data in `db.js` file

```
const School = [
    { class: "First", student: ["sam", "anu", "rahul"], images: ["sam.jpg","anu.jpg","rahul.jpg"] },
    { class: "Second", student: ["anil", "sunil", "nikhil"], images: ["anil.jpg","sunil.jpg","nikhil.jpg"] }
  ];
```

And `School.js`

```
import React from "react";

function Student() {
  const { class, student, images} = data;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{class}</p>
      {student.map((name) => (
        <div
          key={name}
          className="student"
          data-answer={name}>
          {name}-{images} /* <img src={images} alt="stud-img" /> */
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Student;
```

Here data are show like

```
First
sam-sam.jpg,anu.jpg,rahul.jpg
anu-sam.jpg,anu.jpg,rahul.jpg
rahul-sam.jpg,anu.jpg,rahul.jpg
```

I wand result like :

```
First
sam-sam.jpg
anu-anu.jpg
rahul-rahul.jpg
```

How to print data like above, any changes in JSON data, I am new to react please help me to solve this issue, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve that is by using the [second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#syntax) from `map`, the `index`.

But it's important to note that this will only work if the order of the students array and images array match correctly.

```js
function Student() {
  const { class, student, images} = data;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{class}</p>
      {student.map((name, index) => (
        <div
          key={name}
          className="student"
          data-answer={name}>
          {name}-{images[index]} /* <img src={images} alt="stud-img" /> */
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: if we have another array age and roll number how we call them

Comment: If they follow the same pattern of images array you can just use the same approach, `age[index]` and `roll[index]`. If not, you can iterate over them inside of `student.map` by either calling `age.map(...` or `roll.map`.